# Add a checkbox to each row of a ListViewWebpart

Tags: sharepoint, checkbox, wss

I'm working on a WSS 3 site that has a ListViewWebpart displaying various columns.

I need to add a checkbox to each row and a button to the header that will perform a server side action for the selected rows.

Do I need to make my own custom webpart or can the ListViewWebpart support checkboxes?

### Adding checkboxes to each row

I've found a post [Checkbox in ListViewWebpart](http://murugangs.blogspot.com/2007/12/checkbox-in-listviewwebpart.html) which suggests

> ...to add a checkbox, to select multiple
>   listitem, in the custom list, declare
>   a xml string as follows.

```
<Field Type="Computed" ReadOnly="TRUE" Name="ListItemSelection" DisplayName="Select" Sortable="FALSE" Filterable="FALSE" EnableLookup="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ListItemSelection">
<FieldRefs>
<FieldRef Name="ID" />
</FieldRefs>
<DisplayPattern>
<HTML><![CDATA[<input type="checkbox" ]]></HTML>
<HTML><![CDATA[LItemId="]]></HTML>
<Column Name="ID" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
<HTML><![CDATA["/> ]]></HTML>
</DisplayPattern>
</Field>
```

> and call the
>   list.Fields.[AddFieldAsXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.addfieldasxml%28v=office.12%29.aspx)(“xml
>   string”);. Include this as a first
>   column in your custom list’s view.

I'm assuming the latter part requires a SPList. E.g.

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"];
list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(stringWithXmlFieldDefinition);
```

### Adding a button to the header row

One option for the header button is a [CustomAction](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2008/04/29/sharepoint-custom-actions-in-a-list-view-webpart.aspx). This should create a button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [post](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/wsssharepoint-create-custom-listviewwebpart) to create a custom web part, then you can add a check box to your custom web part using the post you have found (Checkbox in ListViewWebpart).

Be aware that,`list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(stringWithXmlFieldDefinition);` can end up adding many duplicated check boxes to you sharepoint. The duplicated can be deleted from database and are located at **AllLists** table, **tp_Fields** column.

To find the right fields, you can search by the list guid.

```
declare @xmlString as xml
Select  @xmlString = tp_Fields
From        [WSS_Content].[dbo].[AllLists]
Where   tp_id ='xxxx'
Select @xmlString
```

then, update the fields

```
declare @string as varchar(max)
set @string ='new value without duplicated checkbox'
UPDATE [WSS Content] . [dbo] . [AlILists)
SET [tp_Fields] = @string
WHERE tp_ID = 'xxx'
```

You can simply add a button by

```
ToolBarButton newbtn = (ToolBarButton)Page.LoadControl("~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ToolBarButton.ascx");
```

but possibly you need create another toolbar to hold the button, you can even create your own toolbar. You just need to put it in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\YourCutomToolBar.ascx`